# phone number text box does not save into database

Tags: php, html, database

It's a student database system where I can add student data, edit student data, delete student data, and search student data from registration number.

Here is where I'm getting a problem. All is ok but phone number will not be saved in mysql database. All other option are edit and insert in database.

I did not get any error when I edit any information or add new data.

When I submit phone number direct from phpmyadmin then from my index page when I put registration number then get all information of student without phone number.

Here is `index.php` code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password ="root";
$database = "college";

$student_reg = "";
$student_name = "";
$father_name = "";
$phone_number = "";
$student_address = "";
$student_course = "";
$student_certificatenumber = "";
$student_email = "";
$student_city = "";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// connect to mysql database
try{
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $ex) {
    echo 'Error';
}

// get values from the form
function getPosts()
{
    $posts = array();
    $posts[7] = $_POST['student_reg'];
    $posts[1] = $_POST['student_name'];
    $posts[2] = $_POST['father_name'];
    $posts[3] = $_POST['phone_number'];
    $posts[4] = $_POST['student_address'];
    $posts[5] = $_POST['student_course'];
    $posts[6] = $_POST['student_certificatenumber'];
    $posts[8] = $_POST['student_email'];
    $posts[9] = $_POST['student_city'];
    return $posts;
}

// Search

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $data = getPosts();

    $search_Query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_reg = $data[7]";

    $search_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $search_Query);

    if($search_Result)
    {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($search_Result))
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_Result))
            {
                $student_reg = $row['student_reg'];
                $student_name = $row['student_name'];
                $father_name = $row['father_name'];
                $phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
                $student_address = $row['student_address'];
                $student_course = $row['student_course'];
                $student_certificatenumber = $row['student_certificatenumber'];
                $student_email = $row['student_email'];
                $student_city = $row['student_city'];
            }
        }else{
            echo 'No Data For This Id';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Result Error';
    }
}


// Insert
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    $insert_Query = "INSERT INTO `students`(`student_reg`, `student_name`, `father_name`, `phone_number`, 

`student_address`, `student_course`, `student_certificatenumber`, `student_email`, `student_city`) VALUES ('$data

[7]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[8]','$data[9]')";
    try{
        $insert_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_Query);

        if($insert_Result)
        {
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Data Inserted';
            }else{
                echo 'Data Not Inserted';
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Error Insert '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}

// Delete
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    $delete_Query = "DELETE FROM `students` WHERE `student_reg` = $data[7]";
    try{
        $delete_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $delete_Query);

        if($delete_Result)
        {
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Data Deleted';
            }else{
                echo 'Data Not Deleted';
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Error Delete '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}

// Edit
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    $update_Query = "UPDATE `students` SET `student_reg`='$data[7]',`student_name`='$data[1]',`father_name`='$data

[2]',`phone_number`='$data[3]',`student_address`='$data[4]',`student_course`='$data

[5]',`student_certificatenumber`='$data[6]',`student_email`='$data[8]',`student_city`='$data[9]' WHERE 

`student_reg` = $data[7]";
    try{
        $update_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $update_Query);

        if($update_Result)
        {
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Data Updated';
            }else{
                echo 'Data Not Updated';
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Error Update '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}



?>


<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP INSERT UPDATE DELETE SEARCH</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="student_reg" placeholder="Student Registration Code" value="<?php echo 

$student_reg;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="student_name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $student_name;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="father_name" placeholder="Student Father Name" value="<?php echo 

$father_name;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="Phone_number" placeholder="Phone Mobile Number" value="<?php echo 

$Phone_number;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="student_address" placeholder="Address" value="<?php echo $student_address;?

>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="student_course" placeholder="Course" value="<?php echo $student_course;?

>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="student_certificatenumber" placeholder="Certificate Number" value="<?php echo 

$student_certificatenumber;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="student_email" placeholder="EMail" value="<?php echo $student_email;?

>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="student_city" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo $student_city;?>"><br><br>
            <div>
                <!-- Input For Add Values To Database-->
                <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add">

                <!-- Input For Edit Values -->
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">

                <!-- Input For Clear Values -->
                <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">

                <!-- Input For Find Values With The given ID -->
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `input`'s name is `Phone_number` and your `$_POST` key is `phone_number`. They are **not** the same... php is case sensitive (like most languages...)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$posts[3] = $_POST['phone_number']
```

is not the same as

```
<input type="text" name="Phone_number"
```

Phone_number is not = to phone_number.  PHP is case sensitive.

Comment: We must have been typing at the same time.  Thanks for down voting though, really encourages new people to participate.  If you were answering, why comment instead of answering?

Comment: I saw the question, saw the problem, started typing. It's rare that I take the time to do so, mainly because I'm busy as hell. Then when I do it gets a down vote. I don't get it. So, since this place is supposed to be about sharing knowledge, why comment instead of answering if you have the answer? Why would anyone down vote the correct answer?  I'm missing something about how this place works?  I realize search before asking, but are you supposed to flame or ignore someone who just needs a second set of eyes on a code issue instead of simply answering them?

Comment: Usually people down-vote the correct answer if it's not really an "answer" but more of a "quick guideline". A typo is an example for that (You need to change `strat` to `start`). Regarding the timing - your answer came 7 minutes after my comment, so you might also got downvote for that by someone.

Answer (score -1):

check datatype of your phonenumber column in mysql database make it of string type...it may solve your problem

Comment: For future reference this would be more useful to the OP if it was posted as a comment on their question rather than an answer.